# What is the suspension of the integers?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm interested to know the homotopy type of the reduced suspension of the integers.

I suspect this should be a countable wedge of spheres, by extending the usual picture that indicates the suspension of a 2-point set is a circle. Is this the case?

Comment: It's a countable wedge of circles, yes.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.